# How to get list of databases from a linked server

Tags: sql-server

I have to look up for results on linked servers' databases. First I should know what dbs are available on a linked server. I tried to use the below query but gives an error.

What would be the proper way?

```
...
set @base_query_db_list = 
'
    select
        ''@server'',
        name,
        database_id,
        create_date
    from @server.sys.databases
'

set @server = '[linked_server_name]'
set @query_db_list = replace(@base_query_db_list, '@server', @server)
insert into @db_list
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query_db_list
...
```

Error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 
Invalid object name '[linked_server_name].sys.databases'.
```

Comment: `[linked_server_name].sys.databases` is 3 part naming: `database.schema.object`. It would try to reference the **database** named `linked_server_name` *not* the object and schema `sys.databases` in an arbitrary database on the linked server `linked_server_name`. To reference a linked server you would need to use 4 part naming `server.database.schema.object`.

Comment: Thx @Larnu! I it is working with `from @server.master.dbo.sysdatabases`